# how to resolve intermittent SQL backup issue?

Tags: sql-server, backup

We have this issue on aprox 100-300 SQL machines each month and it's never re-occuring. If you re-run the backup it will complete. The problem exists in both win2k8 and win2k12 machines.

Backup failes with the following error in the nsrsqlsv.raw.

> A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file
>   "Legato#1978fba8-cf4b-4d3b-8cec-bf2316364b27:" 995(failed to retrieve
>   text for this error. Reason: 15105)..

I found that the 995 is a ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED signal sent to Networker/VDI writer but can't figure out what's sending the signal.

When looking into the SQL logs i find entry's for the same time and db.

> 08/25/2014
>   14:19:05,spid54,Unknown,BackupVirtualDeviceFile::RequestDurableMedia:
>   Flush failure on backup device
>   'Legato#097d3227-43a8-4b2e-ad0a-5cf35a661b63'. Operating system error
>   995(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
>
> 08/25/2014 14:19:05,spid54,Unknown,Error: 18210 Severity: 16
>   State: 1.
>
> 08/25/2014 14:19:05,Backup,Unknown,BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError:
>   write failure on backup device
>   'Legato#097d3227-43a8-4b2e-ad0a-5cf35a661b63'. Operating system error
>   995(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
>
> 08/25/2014 14:19:05,Backup,Unknown,Error: 18210 Severity: 16
>   State: 1.
>
> 08/25/2014 14:19:05,Backup,Unknown,BACKUP failed to complete the
>   command BACKUP LOG RP_DBadminOp. Check the backup application log for
>   detailed messages.
>
> 08/25/2014 14:19:05,Backup,Unknown,Error: 3041 Severity: 16
>   State: 1.

So i can see that there is an issue with the RequestDurableMedia operations and that it fails on doing a flush. But i have no idea on what it mean and what the Flush operation does.
In the file xbsa.messages

> _nwbsa_is_retryable_error: received a retryable network error (Severity 0 Number -13): busy

Is this due to packetloss, latency or other Network related issues?

And please don't ask me for FQDN checks, license or other default troubble shooting. Backup works 5minutes after it fails so there is no DNS failure. We're running a capacity license so can have as many clients i wish to have.

Servers are mostly virtual and having their data stored on EMC VMAX 10K disk over SAN. All physical have the same disk setup.

Comment: Are you backing up directly to Newton share? Can you try to back up locally and then move the backups to network share.

Comment: The issue is with the fileshare we had same issue and it was fileshare which was configured incorrectly. It happens like when you try to write backup for huge database on fileshare it just aborts after half way

Comment: Fix was open regedit navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters Create a New DWORD value with the name: SessTimeout set the value: 360 keep it Hexadecimal Check this link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic768429-391-1.aspx this was answer posted by OP himself. But issue was with windows server 2008 not with Win Server 2012. Do tell if it helps